# Circular symmetry argument in integration

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, integration, skyrmion

I'm working through a book on magnetic skyrmions and in some calculations the integral

$\int d^2 \vec{r}\,  \left(\partial_x \vec{S}\right)\cdot\left(\partial_y \vec{S}\right)$

pops up, where we integrate over the whole space, $\vec{r}=(x,y)$ and $\vec{S}$ is the spin vector.  In the book it's argued that because of the circular symmetry of the skyrmion, this integral is equal to zero. However, I don't see why this would evaluate to be zero. Could someone shed light on why this is true? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can argue that
$$
\int (\partial_\mu {\bf S})\cdot(\partial_\nu {\bf S}) d^2x  \stackrel{\rm def}=I_{\mu\nu}
$$
is unchanged by a rotation of the $x,y$ axes in the plane. As the only SO(2) invariant tensors are $\delta_{\mu\nu}$ and $\epsilon_{\mu\nu}$ and the expression is clearly symmetric in $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$, we must have
$$
\int (\partial_\mu {\bf S})\cdot(\partial_\nu {\bf S}) d^2x  \stackrel{\rm def}=\lambda \delta_{\mu\nu}.
$$
This means that the off diagonal $\mu=x$, $\nu=y$ integral is zero.